# Create Standalone SD Card from a NOOBS installation

Tags: raspbian, noobs

We just setup our raspberry pi as a server. We started with NOOBS 1.2 and installed Raspbian. I just realized that NOOBS 1.2 can't automatically boot into Raspbian.

Is there a way to clone just the OS portion of the SD card and make a bootable disc image that I could use to reformat the SD card with so that it boots directly into Raspbian?

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE**: This doesn't answer the OP's question as it is posted. This is merely a work-around.

Check on the [GitHub NOOBS](https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs) page. While it doesn't  actually allow you to clone the installation, you can just bypass the splashscreen and boot automatically into the selected partition.

From the page:

> How to bypass the Recovery splashscreen and boot directly into a fixed
>   partition
>
> After you have installed your chosen OSes, add the following file to
>   the root directory of NOOBS to force the indicated partition to be
>   booted at power-on.
>
> - Add a text file named autoboot.txt to the root directory of NOOBS.
> - Add boot_partition=[PARTITION NUMBER] to the file and save it to disk.
>
> This will also prevent the splashscreen from being displayed at boot.

As for the partition you are going to be using, my guess is that it will be `/dev/mmcblk0p1`, though I can't be certain, as your installation is going to be different than mine. To find out which partition you are on run `sudo parted`, then run `print`. This is example output for `print` within parted:

```
Model: SD SDC (sd/mmc)
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 8069MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      4194kB  62.9MB  58.7MB  primary  fat16        lba
 2      62.9MB  8069MB  8006MB  primary  ext4
```

The smaller partition is going to be your boot partition. In Raspbian it is anyways. I have yet to use NOOBS very much, so it may be different. The first is also most likely the boot partition, so just take the Disk name (`Disk /dev/mmcblk0:`...) and then tack on `p` and the partition Number (marked below):

```
Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 --->1      4194kB  62.9MB  58.7MB  primary  fat16        lba
     2      62.9MB  8069MB  8006MB  primary  ext4
```

of the first partition. In this case it will be `/dev/mmcblk0p1`. Thus, your `autoboot.txt` file would look like this:

```
boot_partition=1
```

I could be wrong, so if that fails, try `boot_partition=/dev/mmcblk0p1` though 1 is the boot partition number in my case and thus would be what it looks like should go in that file.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the version of NOOBs I have doesn't have this feature :( Which is why I wanted to clone my os and reflash just the os to a card.

Comment: Ah. Well, it is just a work-around. It's worth a shot anyways.

Answer (score 1):

if i were you, i'd [download](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads) clean raspbian image, copy it to the SD card and use it and forget about NOOBS.

actually, that't exactly what i did with my several PIs =)

Comment: I'd like to keep my complete working setup, just without the NOOBS. I'm aware I can start over without NOOBS but the idea is to not lose the work already done.

Comment: are you familiar with the concept of backups? save your files into the svn/git/hg or just a different hdd/network drive and restore 'em back after OS reinstall.

Comment: Yes we have backups. It's just I'd have to flash a new SD Card, install the needed packages, move the files I need to the card via usb, re-license the server software, etc. I can do all of that. I just wondered if I could flash a new SD card with a clone of the current OS partition, without the NOOBS partition. Or if I could somehow upgrade NOOBS or skip the NOOBS boot sequence.